# Using eventlet.corolocal with Celery

Tags: celery, thread-local-storage, eventlet

Does anyone have experience using eventlet.corolocal, especially with celery (with eventlets for workers)?

If so, could you shed some light on what's wrong with the below code sample?

```
...
from eventlet.corolocal import local

...

ev_local = local()

@app.task
def dummy_task(self, a):
  if hasattr(ev_local, a):
    ev_local.a += a
  else:
    ev_local.a = a
  print ev_local.a

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.start()
```

If I now start a celery worker with concurrency, say 5,

```
celery multi start 1 -A process_mss -l info -P eventlet -c 5 --verbose
```

and call the task (dummy_task) 20 times -

```
...

for i in xrange(20):
  dummy_task.delay(1)
```

I see that the 5 eventlets process 4 tasks each (using id returned eventlet.corolocal.get_ident()). But, the eventlets always find ev_local without knowledge of the variable/attr 'a'. So the print statement in dummy_task(...) always prints 1.

Any pointers on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small typo here:

  `if hasattr(ev_local, a):`

Second argument to `hasattr` must be string: `hasattr(ev_local, 'a')`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventlet doesn't guarantee you will receive the same greenthread. In fact, each task may run in a new greenthread.

The greenthread id (eventlet.corolocal.get_ident()) is the memory address of a Python object (I think the greenthread). So when a new greenthread is used to execute the celery task, the thread local storage will "disappear." If you happen to get lucky and a celery task reuses a greenthread, then the information in the thread local storage will reappear.

You can work around it using the prefork threading model.

To date, I have yet to solve this problem.